# C# Try-catch block does not catch an exception it should catch

Tags: c#, exception, selenium-webdriver, uncaught-exception

I have a C# program that scrapes news using Selenium from a website. Most news has an image on the top when opened, but some have a video instead of an image. In those cases, I want to save a default image.

I search for the image element like this: `var imageElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr > td > img"));`. If there is no image, it throws a `NoSuchElementException`, which I handle by logging it on the console and setting up a default image.

However, for some reason, all of a sudden (at least I feel so since I definitely have not changed this part of the code), it stopped doing that and it throws an exception in the `try` part of the `try-catch` block, which goes unhandled.

At first, my code only catches the general `Exception`, but I thought that adding another `catch` in the `try-catch` block would help, but it did not.

Here is that part of my code:

```
try {
  var imageElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr  > td > img"));
  imageSrc = imageElement.GetAttribute("src");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  Console.WriteLine($"Exception when looking for imageElement! {e.Message}");
  imageSrc = "https://digitalfinger.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/no-image-available-icon-6.png";
} catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine($"Exception when looking for imageElement! {e.Message}");
  imageSrc = "https://digitalfinger.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/no-image-available-icon-6.png";
}
```

Here is the entire method:

```
private News GetTheNewsData(ChromeDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

  string imageSrc = "";
  string date = "";
  DateTime dateParsed = DateTime.Now;

  try {
    var imageElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr  > td > img"));
    imageSrc = imageElement.GetAttribute("src");
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception when looking for imageElement! {e.Message}");
    imageSrc = "https://digitalfinger.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/no-image-available-icon-6.png";
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception when looking for imageElement! {e.Message}");
    imageSrc = "https://digitalfinger.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/no-image-available-icon-6.png";
  }

  try {
    //Wait for the title element to load
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h1.title")));
    //Get the title element
    var titleElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.title"));
    var title = titleElement.Text;

    //Wait for the date element to load
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("div.art_author")));
    //Get the date element
    var dateElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.art_author"));

    if (dateElement.Text.StartsWith("Обновена")) {
      var pipeIndex = dateElement.Text.IndexOf('|');
      date = dateElement.Text.Substring("Обновена: ".Length, pipeIndex - "Обновена: ".Length).Trim();
      Console.WriteLine($"Trimmed date: {date}");
    } else {
      date = dateElement.Text.Split(',')[0];
    }

    try {
      dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d MMM yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("bg-BG"), DateTimeStyles.None);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine($"Exception parsing the date! {e.Message}");
      dateParsed = new DateTime(1000, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dateParsed.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

    //Wait for the div with content paragraphs to load
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("div#art_start")));
    //Get the div with content paragraphs
    var divWithContentParagraphs = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#art_start"));
    //Get the content paragraphs
    var contentParagraphs = divWithContentParagraphs.FindElements(By.CssSelector("p"));

    var sterilizedParagraphs = SterilizeTheNews(contentParagraphs);

    var currentNews = new News {
      Title = title,
        Content = sterilizedParagraphs,
        Date = dateParsed,
        ImageUrl = imageSrc
    };

    return currentNews;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception in getting the news data! {e.Message}");

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is when a child catches an exception.  The parent will only be able to capture the same exception if the child does a throw.  Without the throw, an exception can only be caught once.

Comment: just catch the general exception... the GetAttribute() call could also throw... (I'd guess stale element for that call)  You might just want to try/catch those separately, or if/then according to the general exception's type.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full message and stack trace for one of the exceptions that are not being caught.